# How to aggregate Python Pandas dataframe such that value of a variable corresponds to the row a variable is selected in aggfunc?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I have the following data

```
ID        DATE        AGE        COUNT
1         Nat         16         1
1         2021-06-06  19         2
1         2020-01-05  20         3
2         Nat         23         3
2         Nat         16         3
2         2019-02-04  36         12
```

I want to aggregate this so that the `DATE` will be the earliest valid date (in time), while `AGE` will be extracted from the corresponding row the earliest date is selected. The output should be

```
ID        DATE        AGE        COUNT
1         2021-06-06  19         1
2         2019-02-04  36         3
```

My code which gives this error `TypeError: Must provide 'func' or named aggregation **kwargs.`.

```
df_agg = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ID'],
                                values=['DATE', 'AGE'],
                                aggfunc={'DATE': np.min, 'AGE': None, 'COUNT': np.min})
```

I don't want to use `'AGE': np.min` since for ID=1, AGE=16 will be extracted which is not what I want.

///////////// Edits ///////////////

Edits made to provide a more generic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`.first_valid_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas-series-first-valid-index):

```
x = df.loc[df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: x["DATE"].first_valid_index())]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   ID       DATE  AGE
1   1 2021-06-06   19
5   2 2019-02-04   36
```

---

EDIT: Using `.pivot_table()`. You can extract the `"DATE"`/`"AGE"` together as a list, for `"COUNT"` you can use `np.min` or `"min"`. The second step would be explode the `"DATE"`/`"AGE"` list to separate columns:

```
df_agg = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=["ID"],
    values=["DATE", "AGE", "COUNT"],
    aggfunc={
        "DATE": lambda x: df.loc[x.first_valid_index()][
            ["DATE", "AGE"]
        ].tolist(),
        "COUNT": "min",
    },
)
df_agg[["DATE", "AGE"]] = pd.DataFrame(df_agg["DATE"].apply(pd.Series))
print(df_agg)
```

Prints:

```
    COUNT       DATE  AGE
ID                       
1       1 2021-06-06   19
2       3 2019-02-04   36
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely solves the current problem. But I wonder if there is a way I can still use the `pivot_table` or `groupby` functions. That way, I can choose the correct date and extract corrresponding demographic variables, but also possible to extract means/min/max of other variables, if needed.

Comment: @KubiK888 I updated my answer using `.pivot_table()`

Comment: I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`.

Comment: @KubiK888 What pandas version are you using? you can use `.values.tolist()` instead of `.tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

You can sort values and drop the duplicates (sort_index is optional)

```
df.sort_values(['DATE']).drop_duplicates('ID').sort_index()
```

---

```
   ID       DATE  AGE
1   1 2021-06-06   19
5   2 2019-02-04   36
```

With `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df[df['DATE'] == df.groupby("ID")['DATE'].transform('min')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an index, a simple solution would be:

```
def min_val(group):
    group = group.loc[group.DATE.idxmin]
    return group

df.groupby(['ID']).apply(min_val)
```

If you do not have an index you can use:

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['ID']).apply(min_val).drop(columns=['ID'])
```